# Pyinstaller: fatal error, failed to execute script

Tags: python-3.5, pyinstaller

This is a recurring theme, distributing python code seams to be a non-ending issue (I have checked all related answers I could find on SO regarding this).

I have a script containing the following imports:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mbox
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
import glob
import base64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
plt.style.use('bmh')
```

It's basically a GUI containing several buttons (each launching a function that reads from a pandas data frame and shows a graph via a Matplotlib plot) and also a label with a logo.

I've tried my usual tweaking with pyinstaller (and also with and without the label image:

Simple (one file and without):

```
pyinstaller -F -w --noconsole -i icon.ico Script.py
```

Complex:

```
pyinstaller -F -w --noconsole --noupx -p  C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages --hiddenimport pandas --hiddenimport matplotlib --hiddenimport PIL --add-data "image.png;image.png" -i Fuji.ico --log-level=DEBUG Script.py
```

And every variation in between.

I have removed from Pyinstaller/loader/rthooks.dat the line 'PyQt4': ['pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py'] which is know to cause some issues.

I get the same error again and again: [image]

Versions:

Pyinstaller 3.3.1 (/!\ Edit: I tried also with the dev version, same result)

Python 3.5.3

The results from the warn file in debug mode: https://pastebin.com/na0W4TGS

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by pasting the label image to the .exe folder **and also** the platforms folder from:

C:\'Users\USER\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Library\plugins